# Use java to read hdfs blk_.meta file

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

In the data node of Hadoop, there always exists the block file which contains the raw bytes of the data and also the metadata file with the generated stamp and the `.meta` as extension.

I tried to open the meta data in vi and it looks like gibberish content. I am assuming it is some sort of serialized binary format. I took a look at the source code of HDFS and feel like `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockMetadataHeader.readHeader` is the most likely approach to read the metadata.

I downloaded one of the meta files locally and wrote some code in Eclipse.

```
package com.bw;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockMetadataHeader;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataInputStream input = null;
        BlockMetadataHeader header = null;

        try {
            input = new DataInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream("C:/Users/bw/Desktop/blk_1116668343556322736_1551688.meta"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BlockMetadataHeader.readHeader(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(header.getChecksum());
    }
}
```

However, the syntax was right but it errors out with the following message.

```
java.io.IOException: Could not create DataChecksum of type 2 with bytesPerChecksum 512
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.newDataChecksum(DataChecksum.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockMetadataHeader.readHeader(BlockMetadataHeader.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockMetadataHeader.readHeader(BlockMetadataHeader.java:75)
    at com.bwang.Test.main(Test.java:27)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bwang.Test.main(Test.java:32)
```

I searched for the error and barely find any helpful resource. Can anyone help me how to read the metadata of block metadata file?

---

Update, after all, it is the mismatch between the meta file version and the maven Hadoop version.

```
# hadoop version
Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.6.0
```

Then I changed the maven pom file to the following and it worked

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0_05</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're using hadoop pre-0.23.0 library against later version metadata file?

Type 2 was introduced in DataChecksum 3 years ago as part of [HADOOP-7443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7443)

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/DataChecksum.java?r1=1146111&r2=1146300.

Comment: sir, thanks so much for your answer. I can read in the header file now.. I notice that the meta file is about 1MB, but seems like there are only a very few methods that `checksum`, `version`, and `headersize`. Is there any other information in those 1MB?